# Http POST getting canceled by Chrome

Tags: angular, spring-boot, http, cors

I'm trying to send a POST request from my Angular Frontend to my spring boot backend (which is running locally or insinde a docker container, but still locally).

The POST request is getting triggered when I'm clicking a 'create'-Button, which builds up an object and is attached as requests body.

**Clicking the Button leads to this TS function:**

```
createProject() {
    if(this.checkContact()) {
      const contact: Contact = {
        forename: this.forename,
        surname: this.surname,
        address: this.address,
        city: this.city,
        email: this.email,
        mobile: this.mobile
      }
      this.contacts.push(contact);
    }

    const customer: Customer = {
      name: this.customerName,
      address: this.customerAddress,
      city: this.customerCity,
      customerTyp: this.customerType,
      contacts: this.contacts
    }
    this.customers.push(customer);

    const announcement: Announcement = {
      requirement: this.requirements,
      customers: this.customers
    }
    this.announcements.push(announcement);

    const project: NewProjectRequest = {
      name: this.projectName,
      historyEntries: null,
      announcements: this.announcements
    };

    this.service.createProject(project)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
      .subscribe((r) => {
        console.log(project);
      });
      this.router.navigateByUrl("/");
}
```

**The service method being called:**

```
createProject(request: NewProjectRequest) {
    return this.http.post(`${environment.serverUrl}${this.urlCreateProject}`, request);
}
```

In my browsers network tab, I can see that there where 2 requests fired.
The frist one is a OPTIONS request, which is only there to check if the initial request is possible - this one receives a 200 status
The second request is the initial POST request, which is immediately cancled by Chrome.

[screenshot on chromes network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOLK7.png)

**In the canceled POST request:**

- the Headers are looking good
- The payload looks totally fine for me (fully blown json in the body)
- Preview and response tabs: "Failed to load response data: No data found for resource with given identifier"

The weird thing for me is.. running locally, the Project is getting persisted successfully, so the request somehow comes through. So I'm only affraid of possible follow-up errors because of this and ofc I want to get rid of the "canceled" status on the POST request.

In the spring boot backend there is also a sercurity configuration which allows all CORS requests from the Angular frontend.

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().configurationSource(request -> {
                    var cors = new CorsConfiguration();
                    cors.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:4200"));
                    cors.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
                    cors.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
                    return cors;
                }).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(SWAGGER_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
                // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
                // store user's state.
                .exceptionHandling()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        return http.build();
}
```

The response headers also say that all methods for localhost:4200 are allowed:
[Chrome response headers from OPTIONS request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNfME.png)

Answer (score -1):

Your request is being cancelled because the server you are requesting does not support [cross origin requests (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). This occurs when your client and app do not share the same protocol, host and port. For example, your spring-boot app may be running on `localhost:8080`, but your Angular development server is running on `localhost:4200` - same protocol (http), same host (localhost) but different ports (4200 vs 8080).

In a basic deployment, your client/server will be all on the same origin. The browser requests `www.my-app.com`, which returns `index.html` and then your Angular app probably does some http calls to your webservices, something like `www.my-app.com/api/stuff`.

I'm not familiar with spring-boot, but if it's like other web frameworks I've used that have some built-in support for Angular, there may be some configuration you can do to make the two work with each other.

Alternatively, a quick search shows me how to configure CORS for sprint-boot. [Scroll down to the "Global CORS Configuration" section](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/). While in "development" mode, you could configure your app to allow requests from any host. This would allow your current setup to work. I would NOT recommend enabling CORS on your "prod" deployment without fully understanding why you'd need it and the risks it carries.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your detailed Answer! 

At the moment we actually already configured CORS to allow EVERY request coming from http://localhost:4200 (which is our angular server). So I'm not quite sure if there is a problem with our configuration, since GET requests e.g. are working totally fine.
Also i've updated the post with the spring configuration method we're using

Comment: Unfortunately I'm likely not of much more help here then due to my inexperience with spring-boot. My next recommendation would be to examine the response headers of the `OPTIONS` request to ensure that the server is really responding with a "I allow all the things" response.